# Encoding UTF-8-BOM Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

I am trying to identify file encoding in Ruby.

```
file = File.open("filePath", "rw");
file.encoding;
```

But I cannot get UTF-8-BOM encoding even if my file is in such encoding. I get everything but not UTF-8-BOM. 
Might UTF-8-BOM encoding be unsupported in ruby? I dont need open or read file but identify its encoding type.

Comment: Do you just want to know if the file has / starts with a UTF-8 BOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by “UTF-8-BOM” encoding? It’s, in fact, a plain old good “UTF-8” encoding, just prepended with the byte order mark (`EF BB BF`.) BOM has **no effect** on UTF-8. Using of BOM in UTF-8 is not recommended. The summing up: there is no such *encoding*, there is byte order mark that *is supposed to help to identify **the endianness** of the encoding*.

`File.open` is the general purpose stream reader and it does not suggest anything, it might be told to use an explicit encoding (useful for single-byte encodings,) and it might determine the endianness of an encoding, basing on BOM (useful for fixed-width unicode encodings.)

If you want to check that the file has BOM, read 3 bytes from it and compare them against `EF BB BF`.